# Drone CI stuck during build

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, drone.io

I have run a build on Drone CI but it stays stuck on "Step is pending"

I don't have any errors in the logs.
I am using Gitea for git hosting.

This is my .drone.yml

```
kind: pipeline
name: default
type: docker

steps:

- name: build-and-serve
  image: docker:dind
  commands:
  - docker build -t my-app-image .
  - docker run -d -p 80:80 my-app-image

services:

- name: docker
  image: docker:dind\
```

What could possibly go wrong?

I have tried checking the logs, chaning in various ways the .drone.yml (even with debug code only) but nothing changed.

Comment: Where/how do you run the drone runner? Is there one configured? Is it a Docker drone runner? Can you add details?